How to make the disconnection work when we redirect?
Here is the server side code snippet
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('User connected!');

  // getting the room id
  socket.on('roomid', (data) => {
    // console.log(data);
    const roomId = data;

    // after getting the room id from client we will make the socket join the room
    socket.join(data);

    console.log('User joined the room');
  });

  // we fetch the current user details of the socket
  socket.on('userdetails', (data) => {
    // console.log(data)

    // after joining the room we need to update the list of connected users
    const existingClient = connectedClient.find((client) => client.id == data.id);
    if (!existingClient) {
      // same client do not exist so we will add it in the array
      connectedClient.push({ id: data.id, user: data });

      //update the list in the front end
      io.emit('updateClientList', connectedClient);
    }

    // upon disconnection match the client id and remove that from the connected client array
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      connectedClient = connectedClient.filter((client) => client.id != data.id);

      //update the list in the front end
      io.emit('updateClientList', connectedClient);
    });
  });
});

Does not disconnect and update the client on disconnect need to manually add a refresh
to reflect that in the client side

What do you mean when you say redirect? Do you mean an actual URL change or React router route change?
